# In a metric space are the terms $bounded$ and $totally$ $bounded$ interchangeable?

Tags: analysis, metric-spaces, self-learning

The question is: Is there a theorem that says in a metric space a set is bounded if and only if it is totally bounded?

Comment: Bounded is not intrinsic, totally bounded is. But for an explicit example take the disc

Comment: @AlexYoucis: Dear Alex, What do you mean by intrinsic?  Bounded depends on the metric, and totally bounded depends on the uniform structure.  So both depend on more than the topology alone.  Regards,

Comment: @MattE Of course, my comment was only supposed to be intuitive. More correctly I should have said that totally bounded is a component of an intrinsic property (compactness) but boundedness (ostensibly) is not. Perhaps I should have held my tongue WRT that. I just wanted to give the OP the reason why my initial reaction to the question, even if I didn't know a bunch of counterexamples, was that it was obviously no. Of course, I should have been clearer. Also, even my intuition is a little holey since there is no a priori reason bounded couldn't be the component of an intrinsic property. :)

Comment: @AlexYoucis Consider the Euclidean metric on $(0,1),(0,\infty)$. These are homeomorphic as topological spaces, but the first is bounded and totally bounded, whereas the second is neither.

Comment: @Sharkos Sure, I understand that. That's not how I would have used my intuition to build counterexamples though :)

Comment: @AlexYoucis Perhaps a better way of answering what you say is this: totally bounded $\implies$ bounded, and therefore if *totally bounded* is a 'component' of something, so is *bounded*.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

No. Consider $\mathbb N = \{1,2,3,\cdots\}$ with the discrete metric $d(x,y)=0,1$ according to whether or not $x=y$.

This cannot be covered with a finite number of $\epsilon=\frac 1 2$ balls, but no two points are more than $1$ from each other.

Comment: Ok great thank you for the comment. I was thinking about this yesterday but wasn't sure of a counter example. Thank you for your help!

Answer (score 2):

No.  On any infinite set, let the distance between two distinct members be $1$.  That's a metric space that is bounded but not totally bounded.

Comment: Thank you also Michael for your comment.

Comment: Hey, you stole (and generalized) my (completely standard) counterexample! P: